# Optional html attributes in Text.Blaze

Tags: html, haskell

Text.Blaze has an operator ! to add attributes to html:

```
option ! id "bla" ! value "1" ! selected "" $ "Hello!"
```

My question is how can i make attributes optional ?
Right now my code is ugly:

```
option ! id "bla" ! value "1" ! (if x == val then selected "" else someStupidAttribute "")  $ "Hello!"
```

This leads to every html option element to have unnecessary irrelevant attribute just because i have to supply one.

EDIT: I accepted hammar's answer. I created a helper function:

```
(!?) :: Attributable h => h -> (Bool,Attribute) -> h
html !? (True, attr) = html ! attr
html !? _ = html
```

And here's how to use it:

```
option ! id "bla" ! value "1" !? ((k == val), selected "") $ "Hello!"
```

Comment: `!?` is by now in [Text-Blaze-Internal.html](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.7.0.3/docs/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#t:Attributable). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about defining a convenience operator to apply attributes conditionally?

```
(!?) :: Attributable h => h -> Maybe Attribute -> h
html !? (Just attr) = html ! attr
html !? Nothing = html
```

With this, you can write your example as follows.

```
option ! id "bla" ! value "1" !? toMaybe (x == val) (selected "") $ "Hello!"
```

Here, `toMaybe` is just a useful helper for building `Maybe` values, but you can use something else if you wish.

```
toMaybe :: Bool -> a -> Maybe a
toMaybe False _ = Nothing
toMaybe True  x = Just x
```

Comment: Thanks, i like it. My question was really if i am missing something from Text.Blaze itself. BUt if i have to define my own helper function then i can just go with one accepting boolean and attribute.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite trick for pretty conditionals is using list comprehensions; `[foo | x]` will either evaluate to `[foo]` or `[]`. Can we adapt this trick? Well, with a helper function that applies lists of attributes:

```
element !. options = foldr (!) element options -- (!.) = foldr (!)
```

Now you can write something relatively pretty like one of these two (depending on taste):

```
option ! id "bla" ! value "1" !. [selected "" | x == val] $ "Hello!"
option !. [id "bla", value "1"] ++ [selected "" | x == val] $ "Hello!"
```

You may have to add a fixity declaration for `!.`; you can use `:i !` in ghci to see what you're trying to interoperate with.

Comment: Freaking cool. Thank you very much. I upvoted you, but i already accepted other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a better Blaze-specific way of doing this, and I know this isn't terribly readable, but you can do

```
(if x == val then (! selected "") else id) (option ! id "bla" ! value "1") $ "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me - mempty:

```
import Data.Monoid (mempty)
option ! id "bla" ! value "1" ! (if x == val then selected "" else mempty) $ "Hello!"
```